# C order of elements in a struct

Tags: c, struct, valgrind, element

I am pretty new to C and I was wondering if the order of elements in a struct matter.

I have the following struct:

```
struct list
{
    struct list_el *head;
    int size;
}
```

I use this to make a linked list. The head points to the first element and the size shows the amount of elements in the list.

I have also have the following function to initialize the list.

```
typedef struct list list;

list* list_init()
{
    list *list = malloc(sizeof(list));
    if(list)
    {
        list->head = NULL;
        list->size = 0;
        return list;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The program compiles fine, without any errors, warnings or notes, but when I run the program using valgrind it says I have an invalid write of size 4 on the line in the `list_init()` function where I assign 0 to `list->size`. I have the same invalid read/write every time I access the size variable. I have no idea why. Also when I switch the two struct elements around (declare `size` first and then `head`) I get the invalid write on the line where I assign NULL to `head` and then the `size` variable is used just fine. Can anybody explain me why this happens and how I can fix it?

Last note: the struct as it is shown here is defined in an header file while the function is in the C file. Not sure if this is important.

Comment: Using type name as variable name is confusing, so I suggest you should change the name of the variable.

Comment: A good compiler would warn (always enable warnings!) about shadowing a name from an outer scope. Warnings are not just to show some fancy messages.

Comment: @Olaf: GCC 5.3.0 run on the code in the question as: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c ll97.c` does not warn about problems (and that's a pretty stringent set of warning flags).  It's only if you add `-Wshadow` that it protests: `error: declaration of ‘list’ shadows a global declaration [-Werror=shadow]` (an error because of `-Werror`; otherwise, just a warning).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Hmm, sorry, you are right. Just checked my standard SConstruct. I really have `-Wshadow` explicitly included. False memory, I really thought that is in `-Wextra`. Maybe there is too much broken code around.

Comment: @Olaf: Because I don't often write code that runs foul of the problem (after all these years), I don't use `-Wshadow` most of the time.  I periodically do a sweep of my code with vastly more stringent options and occasionally that turns up, but not often.  With code written by others, it is more likely to be a problem.  Using GCC and `-Wshadow` is a good idea, especially while learning.  This is a subtle problem — it's quite a reasonable question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I don't _need_ it either. But It does not matter either to have it. Along with quite some all other warnings which might be useful just in case ... . And yes, as that is none of the commonly recommended warnings, I agree now the question may be rectified (it should be some basic general programming knowledge, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You named the variable with the same name as the type, so `sizeof(list)` is implemented as the size of the variable (pointer), not the size of the struct. The struct has a pointer and a integer, so the size will be larger than a pointer, so access to not allocated place occurred.

Rename the variable.

example:

```
list *list_init(void)
{
    list *list_data = malloc(sizeof(list));
    if (list_data)
    {
        list_data->head = NULL;
        list_data->size = 0;
        return list_data;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```